# CSS odd & even on dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following piece of jQuery applied to an input field to narrow a list of items shown in a table (a real `table`, with `tr` and `td` layout):

```
$(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
        var value = this.value.toLowerCase();

        $(".table").find("tr").each(function(index) {
            if (index === 0) return;
            var id = $(this).find("td").text().toLowerCase();
            $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
        });
    });
});
```

It works perfectly otherwise, but as the `.table` has `.table tr:nth-child(odd)` and `(even)` targeted styling for the initial layout, the odd & even rows get messed up when the list narrowing search filter applies.

So far I've been unlucky with removeClass and addClass when the rows change dynamically, am I missing something essential..?

A JSFiddle example can be check at https://jsfiddle.net/4cf8a01L/3/

Comment: You have to **remove** the items from the DOM (using `.detach()`). Then you add them all back, from a "pool" (an array) of detached elements. You need to (somehow) remember the ordering of the `<tr>` (an attribute like `data-pos`?). If you don't remove from the DOM, all styles will be applied by the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kinda of a hacky way to do it - https://jsfiddle.net/6rk09jb0/1/

add odd and even class

```
.table tr:nth-child(odd),
.table tr.odd.odd {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.table tr:nth-child(even),
.table tr.even.even {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

apply odd and even when filtering

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase();

  var count = 0;

  $(".table").find("tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    var id = $(this).find("td").text().toLowerCase();
    var test = id.indexOf(value) !== -1;
    var className = '';
    if (test) {
      count += 1;
      className = count % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even';
    }
    $(this).toggle(test).attr('class', className);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please, don't do things like `count += 1;`. You should use `className = count++ % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even';` or simply change it to `count++;`. Also, you should avoid repeating `$(this)`. And since you're applying a class to the elements, they will start by not having a class. You should trigger the event by adding `.keyup()` on the last line.

Comment: Thanks, this does the job neatly. For the Fiddle demo at least, now I have to get it working together with http://tablesorter.com/ plugin :)

Comment: @lapingultah You would be better off using https://datatables.net/ (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `:nth-child` takes in to account all child elements, regardless of their visibility. To fix this you could use jQuery to apply your row stripes on visible rows on load of the page and also when the filter is changed, like this:

```js
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
  var $table = $('table');

  $table.find("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
    var id = $(this).find("td").text().toLowerCase().trim();
    $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
  });

  stripeRows($table);
});

function stripeRows($table) {
  $table.find('tr:visible:odd').css('background', '#FFFFFF');
  $table.find('tr:visible:even').css('background', '#C0C0C0');
}
stripeRows($('table'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" autofocus>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>title 1</th>
      <th>title 2</th>
      <th>title 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>goes</td>
      <td>here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>and</td>
      <td>then</td>
      <td>here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>rows</td>
      <td>repeat</td>
      <td>this way</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>consisting</td>
      <td>of hundres</td>
      <td>of rows</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>content</td>
      <td>content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that the above only searches for `tr` within the `tbody`, instead of explicitly excluding the row at index `0`.

Alternatively you can use the CSS you are now, but you need to `remove()` or `detach()` the `tr` when filtering, and then also have a system of putting them back in the correct place, either through sorting or explicitly setting their location.

While the CSS of this solution will be simpler, the logic required will be far more complex.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but this answer really doesn't add much. I'm a bit disappointed with it. @phoa's answer is superior (faster code, no random css thrown in the middle of Javascript) and takes a bit about my comment (which I still agree, but their answer is a lot better). Also, their answer is compatible with older browsers (for those who have to develop for deprecated and unsupported pitfalls).

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. As for the 'random css' thrown in, it can easily be amended to use a class. Also note that you say that the other answer works in older browsers when `:nth-child` is unsupported in <IE9, whereas the above answer will work in any browser down to IE4.

Comment: Nobody uses IE4. IE6-8 is still (very little) used. I just feel that way because of the mixing of CSS and Javascript and the *terribly* slow repeated selector `tr:visible`.

Comment: Then why use browser compatibility with older browsers as a positive point of the other answer? Please feel free to offer an alternative answer. In terms of performance I'd wager the two are very similar as they are both looping through the rows of the table.

Comment: I don't have any alternative. Either it is the (slower) option I refered in the comment or @phoa's answer. I believe that their answer is the natural evolution and improvement of your answer. I still can improve your answer a little. Give me 2 minutes. (Also, `.trim()` doesn't exist on IE8<)

Comment: I know I'm 10 minutes late. Here's an improved version: https://jsfiddle.net/yrnnuumf/1/ It still uses the `:visible` pseudo-selector, but as a filter rather than being on `.find()`. There's a little play around with the classes, but it works. I had to swap the colors of the styles, but it works perfectly. It should be (somewhat) faster. With a little more time, it could be a full jQuery plugin with decent options.

Comment: A bit better: https://jsfiddle.net/yrnnuumf/3/ (skips the first tr, if asked to, and lets you use a selector and specify classes).

Comment: I double checked the performance. To test I used `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` and entered the word 'data' in the input, raising 4 events. Yours is slower than mine when there is a lot of rows, but gets faster with less data: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/yrnnuumf/4/ (result: http://i.imgur.com/OHyMGOV.png). Mine is faster with more data, but the speed advantage is lost for fewer rows: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/umeuc4j4/ (result: http://i.imgur.com/CyRVWeW.png)

Comment: I tested the code multiple times to make sure it wasn't a fluke. Results are consistent. Overall, I think if you're really that worried about a ~1ms difference, then you really shouldn't be using jQuery at all :)

Comment: Thank you Rory. Your approach works too, however the one suggested by Phoa is a bit neater (as in "shorter").

Comment: @lapingultah I have to disagree. This answer is actually shorter. It just has more text horizontally.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you provide the code you've used?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel All linked in the fiddles

Comment: I've noticed something. You're applying the style to the first row. On the code provided by the O.P., the first row doesn't have a background. Maybe that check is that slows my code?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Even with that amended performance isn't affected. Similar results: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/umeuc4j4/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This one is **slightly** faster: https://jsfiddle.net/bhwoapqd/ All I've changed was that `find` that was split between a `.find('tr')` and a `filter(':visible')`. Then, to add the color, I've simply filtered (again) by odd and even. I still can improve it.

Comment: Using https://jsfiddle.net/uamqLvfz/ shows a time between 0-5ms. Comparing to yours that shows between 2-6ms. Mine is in no way better looking or easier to learn! Basically, I cheat and skip jQuery to add the background.